# py2exe with PyQt4

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, py2exe, elementtree

I keep getting this issue when trying to convert my PyQt4 project. It comes up saying I have 4 modules missing. I have shown what I get below.

```
  4 missing Modules
  ------------------
? ElementPath                         imported from elementtree.ElementTree
? ElementTree                         imported from PyQt4.uic.uiparser
? PyQt4.elementtree                   imported from PyQt4.uic.uiparser
? PyQt4.uic.port_v2                   imported from PyQt4.uic, PyQt4.uic.Compiler.qtproxies, PyQt4.uic.icon_cache, PyQt4.uic.objcreator, PyQt4.uic.properties
Building 'dist\main.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python33.dll to dist
Copy C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd to dist\win32api.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyodbc.pyd to dist\pyodbc.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd to dist\PyQt4.QtCore.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32\_win32sysloader.pyd to      dist\_win32sysloader.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd to dist\PyQt4.QtGui.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32\win32evtlog.pyd to dist\win32evtlog.pyd

Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd to dist\_elementtree.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Python33\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy DLL C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore4.dll to dist\
Copy ExtensionDLL C:\Windows\system32\pywintypes33.dll to dist\
```

I have installed ElementTree and I don't know what is happening.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages py2exe has problems finding, you can help py2exe by setting the 'packages' option.

E.g.
package = ['elementtree', 'PyQt4']

Comment: Nope, I add elementtree to the includes and it still can't find it